# ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'isRestored'. Find more a

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
   <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <mat-radio-button formControlName="isRestored" value="1">
           Option **strong text**1
     </mat-radio-button >
     <mat-radio-button formControlName="isRestored" value="2">
           Option 2
     </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-radio-group>
```

I can't select option with material radio button

Comment: <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<mat-radio-button formControlName="isRestored" value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button >
<mat-radio-button formControlName="isRestored" value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-form-field>
</mat-radio-group>
I can't select option with material radio button

Comment: See in the [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples) that the "NgModel" or the FormControlName is related to the mat-radio-group tag, not to the mat-radio-button: `<mat-radio-group formControlName="isRestored">...</mat-radio-group>` I know that in an input type="radio" the formControlName is related to the tag input, but in material mat-radio-button not